# Cannot authenticate SSO in Angular 5. Missing 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: angular, single-sign-on

I am trying to authenticate a user with SSO. I am stuck at using POST to request the access token from the API server.

I have tried adding the header manually using an Interceptor:

```
import { Injectable, NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpEvent, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpHandler } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class HttpRequestInteceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const dupReq = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://login.eveonline.com/oauth/token')});

        return next.handle(dupReq);

    }
};

@NgModule({
    providers: [
        {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpRequestInteceptor, multi: true
        }
    ]
})
export class InterceptorModule { }
```

I attempted this solution because adding the header in 'httpOptions.headers' did not do the trick... I got the idea from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MN2WkxPnGTo, and this documentation: https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses

Here is my app.module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthWithEveService } from './auth-with-eve.service';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { UserHasAuthenticatedComponent } from './user-has-authenticated/user-has-authenticated.component';
import { UserLoginComponent } from './user-login/user-login.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpRequestInteceptor, InterceptorModule } from './intercept.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserHasAuthenticatedComponent,
    UserLoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    InterceptorModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthWithEveService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And here is the service handling the POST:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

const authorize_url: string = 'https://login.eveonline.com/oauth/authorize/';
const response_type: string = '?response_type=code';
const redirect_uri: string = '&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/userHasAuthenticated/callback';

const client_id: string = '&client_id='+client_id_val;

const scope: string = '&scope=esi-skills.read_skills.v1 esi-wallet.read_character_wallet.v1';


const tokenPOSTUrl = 'https://login.eveonline.com/oauth/token';

@Injectable()
export class AuthWithEveService {

  constructor(

    private http: HttpClient
  ) {}

  exchangeAuthForToken(authCode: string){

    let body = new HttpParams();
    body.set('grant_type', 'authorization');
    body.set('code', authCode);

    let httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        .set('Authorization', 'Basic MDBiNzU0NTQwODllNGE1ZGFiODcwY2UzNzBlN2ExNTI6SmZLKF14RmpzMno2M248MSR0NEJDbi9dQ3JGbG1B')        
    };

    return this.http.post(tokenPOSTUrl, body, httpOptions);
  }

  SSOUrl(): string {
    return authorize_url
          + response_type
          + redirect_uri
          + client_id
          + scope;
  }

}
```

I have been working on this for six days now, and am dead in the water at this point. Where am I messing up, after trying these solutions, with adding the proper header to this POST request? I need to get the token in order to access this API.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In case the server is not on the same domain as the web app, each response from the server needs to contain Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. This is for security reasons.

There is no other way to solve this problem.

Comment: Aye, turns out I was trying to use server-side authentication on a client-side app... I was able to use 'implicit flow' to get things working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. This header is sent by the server and added to the response (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin)). It looks like the eve-online server is not allowing your origin here.

If you already have valid credentials for some of the eveonline API you should set the `withCredentials` Option to `true` for those requests.

Comment: I have reviewed this page http://eveonline-third-party-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sso/implicitflow.html and it seems like I was trying to access the data using the wrong 'flow' for an SPA. I am now managing to get the token using 'Implicit Flow'...

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to authenticate using methods meant for server-side applications... As my application is client-side, I needed to use 'implicit flow' by changing the 'response_type' query from 'code' to 'token'.

Doing this returned a fragment with the access_token, whereas before my POST request was missing the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header and would NOT return as a valid request.